# OWA works from Browser and MS Outlook but fails from Evolution-EWS

Tags: email, evolution

Here is my setup:

1. I have a windows PC on which I could easily configure and run MS Outlook with the relevant OWA link for the Exchange Server.
2. From the Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I can also access the OWA page for the Exchange Server using Firefox. It gives a security error about the certificate, but if I tell it to proceed nonetheless, then it does. And I can login and access my emails, calendar, etc.
3. I installed Evolution and Evolution-EWS and set it up to work with the OWA Exchange server. Here things got interesting.
4. When I entered username and the Host URL as shown below, I pressed `Fetch URL`, and got the "OAB URL" successfully from the server. Also I pressed then `Check for Supported Types` under `Authentication` and *apparently* the server replied and the authentication method changed from the previous default selection of NLTM to `Kerberos`. So far so good. It seems it worked.

[image]

5. After that I proceeded forward & pressed ok and clicked `Send/Receive` from the main menu. Unfortunately, this never worked. I am always getting the error:

> "No response: SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate".

Also curiously, I observed, when I disabled this account and tried to make a new account (thinking that I may have messed up some setting when doing the configuration for the email/EWS the first time), I realized that the `Fetch URL` action, which I could do successfully the first time, is no longer successful and returns the same error as above.

[image]

6. Final observation: Now and then, I get prompted by Evolution to enter my password. I do. But despite repeatedly pressing OK, the dialog just keeps popping up until I hit cancel and then evolution never again asks me for my password, but the original error reappears.

In the log in the background, I can see:

```
(evolution:2734): camel-CRITICAL **: 13:34:28.946: camel_network_service_can_reach: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to create a Kerberos ticket with the user identity of someone that has a valid Windows Active Directory account. see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30203#issuecomment-395990520

Comment: Ok. I am not in a position to speak about kerberos as I know too little about kerberos. But I thought if I could login from Windows, from Firefox on Ubuntu, then I should have a valid account that would let me also login from evolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't try this last year. I just switched the Authentication scheme to "**Basic**" and then just pressed "OK". And then, I saw my inbox (even though pressing "*Check for Supported Types*" had given an error on the previous screen.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off switching to Thunderbird and using the OWL extension.
[Owl for Exchange](https://www.beonex.com/owl/)

There is a free trial and then it costs 10 euros per year. My experience has been that it works well to access email, calendar, and contacts for EWS and OWA and is well worth the money. I have tried Evolution and Kmail with little to no success. If you are able to find a way for OWA to work reliably in Evolution please post a response here.

Comment: Sorry for the very late feedback. I tried this today and I could not login at all. I get all the time `Could not talk to the server. Is the server name correct? Does your Internet work?`. While right next to the thunderbird, I have a firefox running from which I can login any time. Could it be a case of blocked ports, I wonder? I am sitting behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: It could also be that "owl for exchange" does not establish a connection to the company server, because the company server has an expired certificate. On Firefox, this warning comes up but I just bulldoze ahead, as I trust the server. Dunno how "Owl for Exchange" handles this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Go through desktop Settings. There you can find "Online Accounts". Click "Microsoft Exchange Account" and give your credentials their, not in Evolution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ioannis. I try it on Monday when I am back at work and get back to you on how it worked.

Comment: This is months later, but I just wanted to give feedback, that I could not find any "Online Accounts" in the "Desktop Settings". Which Window Manager are you using?